# How to read the assembly version using Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection

I've got a .dll from a NuGet package that I use in a Blazor WebAssembly application. I want to be able to read the version of it.

Currently I read the version like so:

```
FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(contentRootPath, @"bin\debug\net6.0\AssemblyName.dll"));
var version = $"{fileVersionInfo.FileDescription} ({fileVersionInfo.FileVersion})";
```

Instead of writing a path like this `bin\debug\net6.0\AssemblyName.dll` how can I load the assembly and use Reflection to get the version?

Comment: Try `typeof(ClassFromPackage).GetAssembly().GetName().Version`

Comment: I can't call GetAssembly() on such a statement

Comment: @Bhav then `Assembly.Load` or similar the dll, and read from there? Note that a lot of libs use `AssemblyVersionAttribute` and `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue using `typeof(ClassFromPackage).Assembly.GetName().Version`.